# problem in my enemy effect script not work with more than 1 in the same enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make effect for my enemy if the player is near to the enemy decrease the player speed its work fine but if there's one of the same enemies in the filed has the same script or work if there's more all of them are near to the player not work if there's more then one of the same enemy one near to the the player and the other not here's the question 
how to make enemy does the effect if there's more then one of the same enemy that has the same effect and only one near the player or more ?
here is my effect script

```
void Update () {
        if (Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position) < 20) {
                //    if the enemy near effect
             player.speed = 5f;
        } else {
             player.speed = 10f;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want multiple enemies to slow the player down further? Or do you want to play some particle effect on the enemy when the player is near? Finally, what is this script attached to, the player, or the enemy?

Comment: I think you shouldn't directly change the players properties at this position, especially setting it back in your else-branch will override all other effects. Maybe add a slowDown(int) method to your player and keep track of how many slowDown-effects are present on your player object and let the player decide when to speed up, and what's the minimum and maximum speed. Also don't use this else-path when you haven't entered the players range before, only call it when you leave the players range so the player can keep track of the number of effects on itself.

Comment: @aaronedmistone multiple enemies do slow to the player and this script in the enemy

Comment: @Compufreak any code example

Comment: You should consider using OnTriggerEnter instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't require you to add or change the location of scripts and/or add any more components to the object.

By using a short buffer of time and only removing the slow if the "enemy" was previously slowing, you can do without the extra steps.

This is not the BEST way of doing this, some great suggestions in the comments, but it is A way of doing this.

Tested and confirmed to work in Unity.

```
private float timeUntilSlowEnds = 0;
private bool isSlowing = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position) < 20)
    {
        //1/4 second of slow time
        timeUntilSlowEnds = 0.25f;
        isSlowing = true;
    }

    if(timeUntilSlowEnds <= 0)
    {
        if(isSlowing)
        {
            //only reset player speed if ending slow
            isSlowing = false;
            player.speed = 10.0f;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //slow the player each frame and decrease the timer
        player.speed =  5.0f;
        timeUntilSlowEnds -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```